# Storing element into array but having array index update after in Java

Tags: java, arrays, element

I'm pretty new to java so I was just practicing some of the things I've learned and been playing around with making a bank program that stores customer accounts etc. This is the very beginning where I have an array called "accounts" of the type Customer which is a class I made that takes 3 args in user's name, password, and account number.

I want to make that array to store all the customers this way, as you can see from the method "addAcc". Here I add the new customer object into the customer type array as the first element, but I'm unsure how to add the next customer at the NEXT array index, how do I make the index update when I next call this method to add another user? Or is there another way to go about this?

```
public class Bank {
        private double interest_rate = 1.01; // interest rate 
        private Customer[] accounts = new Customer[1000]; // array to store accounts

    // adds new customer 
    public void addAcc (String user, String pass, int accNum) {
        Customer accID = new Customer(user,pass,accNum);
        this.accounts[0] = accID; 
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `ArrayList` instead of Array? so you need not bother the capacity of array.

Comment: I knew that is a possibility, but with an array is there no way to write it in a way so when I next add another element it adds it to the next index instead of rewriting the first? I still would want to learn this even if I end up using ArrayList

Comment: You can add an instance variable and initialize it to zero, and every time you call `addAcc` you increment it by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a counter variable , which will keep track of how many customer has been added

```
public class Bank {
    private double interest_rate = 1.01; // interest rate 
    private Customer[] accounts = new Customer[1000]; // array to store accounts
    private int counter=0;

// adds new customer 
public void addAcc (String user, String pass, int accNum) {
    Customer accID = new Customer(user,pass,accNum);
    this.accounts[counter++] = accID; 
}
```

Comment: Ok but when does this counter go up? With "counter++" does it go up by 1 every time I call this method to add a new member?

Comment: yes first time you will call it it will store the customer at 0 index and after storing at 0 index it will increment by 1, next time you will add, it will store at index 1 and then it will increment by 1 makings its value 2

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to use an `ArrayList`:

```
public class Bank {
    private double interest_rate = 1.01;
    private List<Customer> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addAcc (String user, String pass, int accNum) {
        Customer accID = new Customer(user, pass, accNum);
        this.accounts.add(accID); 
    }
}
```

This solution is safer too, because the array list dynamically resizes itself as needed. With the first solution using an array you would have an error when the capacity of the array is reached.

For the record, as an inferior alternative, you could keep a count:

```
public class Bank {
    private double interest_rate = 1.01; // interest rate 
    private Customer[] accounts = new Customer[1000]; // array to store accounts
    private lastIndex = -1;

    // adds new customer 
    public void addAcc (String user, String pass, int accNum) {
        Customer accID = new Customer(user,pass,accNum);
        this.accounts[++lastIndex] = accID; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use an Collection instead of an array. May be a ArrayList
But if you still like to use array and continue then you have to check what is the next array element is null and add the new object to that. For this either you can go through the array each and every time or have a index and update that index when adding an account

e.g.

```
public class Bank {
        private static nextIndex = 0;
        private double interest_rate = 1.01; // interest rate 
        private Customer[] accounts = new Customer[1000]; // array to store accounts

    // adds new customer 
    public void addAcc (String user, String pass, int accNum) {
        Customer accID = new Customer(user,pass,accNum);
        this.accounts[nextIndex++] = accID; 
    }
```